# Wrong implementation search a record using hash tables. No results found?

Tags: c, list, hash, hashtable, bucket

I'm trying to search for an array of struct one record by one field (`id`).
The code compile, but does not work. I think that is a problem of creating a hash table. But cannot fix the problem, I am a beginner with hash tables, is it OK to create a hash table of a size of numbers of elements? Anyway, time to access is **O(1)** so I use only a lot of memory right?

Here's there is my complete code, thanks in advance for each advice/comment.

These are my adt:

```
typedef struct _SPerson {
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char id[20];
    char telephone[20];
} SPerson;

typedef struct SInfo {
    int key;
    SPerson value;
} TInfo;

struct SNode_list {    /*list node*/
    TInfo information;          /*data->key and value*/                            
    struct LNode *next; /*pointer to next element*/
};

typedef struct SNode_list LNode;    // LNode single element of list 
typedef LNode *List;

/*hash table struct*/
typedef struct _HashTable {
    int bucket_number;
    List *bucket;
} HashTable;
```

I have an array of 20000 records loaded in 
`SPerson Archive[20000];`

In my function to search a data I do this:

```
void search_using_hash_table(SPerson Archive[], int ne) {
    HashTable *ht = hashtable_create(ne);
    SPerson *app_record
    char *app = get_string();
    for (i = 0; i < ne; i++)       /*Creating Hash-Table*/
        hashtable_insert(ht, i, Archive[i]);
    app_record = hashtable_search(ht, app);
    if (app != NULL)
        printf("\n\nFound.\n %s %s %s %s\n",
               app->id, app->surname, app->name, app->telephone);
    else
        printf("\n\nNot found.\n");
}
```

These are my functions:

Insert

```
void hashtable_insert(HashTable *ht, int key, SPerson value) {
    TInfo info;
    LNode *node;
    unsigned h;
    info.key = key;
    info.value = value;
    h = hash(value.id) % ht->bucket_number;

    node = list_search_unordered(ht->bucket[h], info);  

    if (node == NULL)   /*no collision*/
        ht->bucket[h] = list_insert_at_index(ht->bucket[h], info);
    else                /*push*/
        node->information = info;
}
```

Search

```
SPerson *hashtable_search(HashTable *ht, char *key) {
    unsigned h = hash(key) % ht->bucket_number;      
    TInfo info;
    info.key = key;
    LNode *node = list_search_unordered(ht->bucket[h], info);   
    if (node == NULL)
        return NULL;                                             
    else
        return &node->information.value;
}
```

List search

```
LNode *list_search_unordered(List list, TInfo info) {
    LNode *curr;
    curr = list;

    while ((curr != NULL) && !equal(info, curr->information)) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (curr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
        return curr;
}
```

Equal

```
bool equal(TInfo a, TInfo b) {
    return a.key == b.key;
}
```

Create

```
HashTable *hashtable_create(int buckets) {
    int i;
    HashTable *p = (HashTable *)malloc(sizeof(HashTable));  /*allocation*/
    assert(p != NULL);      /*assert verificate if allocation went ok*/
    assert(buckets > 0);        

    p->bucket_number = buckets;
    p->bucket = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List)*buckets);   
    assert(p->bucket != NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
        p->bucket[i] = NULL;    

    return p;
}
```

Hash algorithm

```
unsigned long hash(unsigned char *str) { /*djb algorithm*/
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hashing the `ids` while storing and when searching you are using hashed `key`s to search which are not already hashed so they will never be equal.

```
 void hashtable_insert(HashTable *ht, int key, SPerson value)
  {
   TInfo info;
   LNode *node;
   unsigned h;
   info.key = key;
   info.value = value;
   h = hash(value.id) % ht->bucket_number;...

 SPerson *hashtable_search(HashTable *ht, char* key)
 {
   unsigned h = hash(key) % ht->bucket_number;       
   TInfo info;
   info.key = key;
   LNode *node = list_search_unordered(ht->bucket[h], info);...
```

Comment: So i should substituite int key with char* key?

Comment: In `hashtable_search`, you get the `h` value from _key_, using `unsigned h = hash(key) % ht->bucket_number;`.  **But** in `hashtable_insert`, you calculate `h` _differently_, **not** using the key but using the value instead: `h = hash(value.id) % ht->bucket_number;`.  This is what @MajeedSiddiqui is saying.  You should calculate `h` the same way in both functions.